# Is this way of sending messages to a queue thread-safe?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am using an instance of [JmsTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html) from Spring 4.3.30 to write messages to a message queue. The code looks like this:

```java
public void sendObjectMessage(final Serializable msg, final Long scheduledDelaySeconds) {
    try {
        this.jmsTemplate.send(this.queue, new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(final Session session) throws JMSException {
                Message m = session.createObjectMessage(msg);
                if (scheduledDelaySeconds != null){
                    m.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, 1000 * scheduledDelaySeconds);
                }
                return m;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logging.logError("Error sending MQ object message", e);
    }
}
```

Also, in the code above `this.queue` is an instance of

`org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue`

So I wonder if this usage of `this.jmsTemplate` and of `this.queue` is thread safe.

What will happen if this code is called simultaneously within multiple threads (while using these shared instances of the `JmsTemplate` and of the queue)? Could that cause any problems?

Comment: According to [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch21s02.html#:~:text=Instances%20of%20the%20JmsTemplate%20class,shared%20reference%20into%20multiple%20collaborators.), `JmsTemplate` is thread safe: "Instances of the JmsTemplate class are thread-safe once configured.". Your `MessageCreator ` is stateless. What are your concerns?

Comment: @gdomo Well, I had a concern because I didn't know about this quote which you posted here. What about the `this.queue` instance. Can it get messed up when accessed from multiple threads (which call `sendObjectMessage`)?

Comment: I know the `MessageCreator` instance is not a problem, it's created each time when `sendObjectMessage` is called so it can cause no issues related to multi-threading.

Comment: Using `this.queue` is OK if it's final. Otherwise it depends, however if it not changes then usually also OK

Comment: FWIW, you should try to avoid JMS `ObjectMessage` if at all possible. It depends on Java serialization to marshal and unmarshal the object payload. This process is generally considered unsafe, because a malicious payload can exploit the host system. Lots of CVEs have been created for this which is why most JMS providers force users to explicitly whitelist packages that can be exchanged using `ObjectMessage` messages. Aside from the security issues Java serialization is _slow_.

Comment: @JustinBertram The Spring version which we are using is 4.3.30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have any problems.

As noted in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.30.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-jmstemplate):

> Instances of the `JmsTemplate` class are *thread-safe once configured*. This is important because it means that you can configure a single instance of a `JmsTemplate` and then safely inject this shared reference into multiple collaborators. To be clear, the `JmsTemplate` is stateful, in that it maintains a reference to a `ConnectionFactory`, but this state is *not* conversational state.

Also, a JMS destination (e.g. [`ActiveMQQueue`](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/main/activemq-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQQueue.java) which extends [`ActiveMQDestination`](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/main/activemq-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQDestination.java) which implements [`javax.jms.Destination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Destination.html)) is one of the few thread-safe objects in JMS. From [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Destination.html):

> `Destination` objects support concurrent use.

Comment: OK, thank you. This answer gives me more confidence to continue without doing any major redesign here.

Comment: OK, sure... Btw, do you have any reference or doc page which says that `org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue` is thread-safe?